# what is a root server hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, root

While searching online for dedicated hosting servers i stumble on some websites offering root servers for great prices compared to other dedi servers while features were also great.

Does anyone know what root servers is all about?

Comment: not sure whether I had poor luck with Bluehost: cheap no-root provider with arcane UIs and I felt it too restrictive. I am now looking for root servers where I could act a bit more independently, a bit like on my own machines. I think it is worth the investment if you want to work on your own and don't want to get stopped by hosting oddities but do not pay overprice.

Answer (score 4):

Could it simply be that the host is offerent root access to their servers while the others are more a 'managed' server?

Root access means that you can run tasks and applications as the system's administrator, you basically have no restraints.

Comment: ... and you have to maintain the system yourself.

Comment: @David Not necessarily. Some hosts will maintain the system but allow root access as well (so you can CHOWN folders, install additional packages, restart services, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's any difference - I've yet to personally experience a dedicated server provider that didn't provide root access (either by default, or on request). I suspect they're just using slightly different terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing in an answer even though the question is 6 years old. I see that some of the providers which advertise 'Root Servers' base their offering on hypervisors such as Virtuozzo which is container based. One such provider is [serverloft.eu](http://www.serverloft.eu/rootservers/rootservers-compare.php). I believe some providers will market this type of  product as a VPS.

Thus, we're not talking about traditional virtualization but [containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/).

I have not tried any of these offerings myself, so I can't say how good / bad they are.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a root server is a server where you have root access (full privileges) to it.

this most likely means it's a virtual server, so you can do whatever you was (even destroy it) and it won't affect other people who have purchased servers from the company.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the answer is, I'm concerned about a provider that could not clearly articulate what they mean. (Probably the difference between a virtual server and an account on a shared server). I'm also concerned about the experience a user will have who didn't know the difference immediately, unless the primary goal is as a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

The server with root privileges to host your contents. The provider will be giving you some  Virtual Server with some limited space (if you want more space and performance, you may have to more)to maintain yourself with a dedicated ip to it.

Example :http://www.linode.com/

Comment: any idea of any openbsd root hosting? The linode has some good options though.

Comment: check out this, They have the solution rootbsd.net